# Passing a function from a react component to a function used in rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components

I want to pass a function from a react component to another function. Due to the fact that I need to use GraphQL queries the function isn't allowed to be a react component because react hooks aren't allowed to be defined in components. But when I just pass the function as argument I recieve the error "handleSomething is not a function". Is there any possible way to do that or do I need to adapt the structure? My main goal is to do the mutation and then change the state so that the called function will be kind of closed. For example if hello is false the TestFunction won't be called.

Example :

```
    export class TestClass extends React.Component{
            
              constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.handleSomething= this.handleSomething.bind(this);
                this.state = {
                   hello: true;
                };
              }
            
              handleSomething(){
                this.setState({hello:false});
              }
              
              render(){
                return(
                    <div>
                         ...
                        <TestFunction handleSomething={this.handleSomething}/>
                         ...
                    </div>
                )
              }
           }
        
  function TestFuntion(handleSomething){
        
          const [ testMutation, { loading, error, data}] = useMutation(TEST_MUTATION);
          
          if (loading) return 'Submitting...';
        
          if (error) return `Submission error! ${JSON.stringify(error, null, 2)}`;
        
          if(data != undefined) handleSomething();
        
          return(
            //here the mutation will be done
          )
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to destructure the `handleSomething` within the `TestFucntion` as it's being passed as a property in the `"props"` object passed to `TestFunction`.

Note the curly braces.

```
  function TestFucntion({handleSomething}){
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I now pass a "props" argument where I declare a handleSomthing with this.handleSomething. In this way it works when I call props.handleSomething()